# Links brought in after loading a page through jquery AJAX do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, mobile

Running into an issue with a mobile app. We are doing an jQuery ajax to call in a remote page off our sever (using Cordova as the shell). This brings in the remote code (bare-bone HTML) and we plan to use local resource to style it.

```
getMyPage: function() {

        $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "http://localhost:8888/shell/",
           crossDomain: true,
           timeout: 10000,
           success: function(data) {
               $("appbody").html(data);
           },
           error: function( xhr,err ) {
               alert('Cannot Connect to the Internet');
           }
        });

    }
```

It brings in the page fine, but when we click on any of the links (served from the CMS Drupal) nothing happens. Through inspector it thinks the files are local using the `file://` prefix which do not exist. Anyone know how to make those links perform the same AJAX call to the remote server?

i.e all the links perform the same ajax GET call.

Comment: I would do following: 1.) Use absolute paths served from the CMS on that html page. OR 2.) Loop through the links and append/replace the http://linktoyourserver.com in JavaScript

Comment: And that will then read the url and pull the data? Is it really that simple?

Comment: It should, I think. What you tell me seems as if your CMS sends a link like this `<a href="/images/my.jpg">My Link</a>`. Cordova will then think its `file://` You can paste and show us the html data coming from the server.

Comment: No luck it just navigates me to that page on the server.

Comment: Isn`t that what you wanted?

Comment: Not entirely. Need the links to perform the ajax call to get that page and bring it back to the app. Does that require a listener to bind links or something?